# How is realloc implemented in the C standard library?

Tags: c, realloc

I can't find any source code for the `realloc` function and it seems to break the fundamental rule of C: it doesn't take the length of the memory to reallocate.

1. How is memory reallocated without knowing the length of the original memory?
2. How could I implement this function myself?

Comment: Memory allocated with `malloc` usually has a header which contains this information, usually located in memory just before the pointer returned by malloc (implementations may differ but this is a common way to do it). This information is internal to the C library. This is what allows `free` to work without taking a size parameter. If you want to implement `realloc` you'll probably want to implement `malloc` and friends too.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/esmil/musl/blob/master/src/malloc/malloc.c) you can see it yourself.

Comment: @StaceyGirl The musl implementation for malloc and friends is confusing, and, in my opinion, less than readable. Mine is slightly better (which I can provide a link to soon, provided it passes the testsuite.

Comment: @JL2210 It is real, complete and efficient (in its ability to actually resize the chunk, including `mremap` usage) implementation in a single file.

Comment: `realloc` and `free` are only defined when the pointer passed is for memory previously allocated with a related allocation routine (or is a null pointer). Those routines work together to keep information about the allocations they have provided. So, when passing a pointer to `realloc` or `free`, you do not need pass the length of the memory that was allocated because the routines already have that information.

Comment: For an [awkwardly written, but good basic malloc/realloc introduction](https://github.com/zyfjeff/C-HOW-TO/blob/master/c-malloc/Malloc_tutorial.pdf) work though this 32-bit tutorial (with care you can extend it to handle 64-bit as well) Note there are numerous strategies to handling chunks of memory such as using a using a *"boundary tag"*. E.g. see [Paper by Paul Wilson](ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/garbage/allocsrv.ps)

Comment: @StaceyGirl That doesn't mean it's comprehensible or readable.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That tutorial is old and uses `sbrk`. Implementations nowadays use `mmap`.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but from the structure standpoint and capturing the metadata, it's not bad at all -- whether you use `mmap` or `sbrk`. But, yes, most allocation implementations are `mmap` now rather than playing with the break.

Comment: There is sample code for `malloc` `realloc` and `free` in K&R.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" standard C library?  There isn't just one.  Each operating system has its own, and they may implement `realloc` and other functions in different ways, so long as the requirements of the C standard are met.  Some of them publish their source code, and you can read it; others   may be closed-source.

Comment: There is no such "fundamental rule".

Comment: Of course there is

Answer (score 4):

There are at least 3 considerations that make it difficult or impossible to implement `realloc` entirely in "userland" C.

1. Interacting with the same data structures that `malloc` and `free` use.
2. `malloc` and `realloc` are required to return storage that is suitably aligned for any object. Until C11 we have not had all the necessary macros to calculate this alignment 100% portably.
3. There's a tricksy language-lawyerly reason that `malloc` and `realloc` cannot be implemented in portable C. I may be garbling the terminology here, but the problem is that after the function has computed the pointer value that it will return, it has no means to relinquish the "effective type" which has become associated with the storage. So even if you can get your versions to work, it is *de facto* non-standard.

Comment: naah, 3 is slightly off ... the thing was that you cannot do a `malloc` that returns bytes from `char []` because it has a declared type, and the C standard does not provide any way to return bytes without declared type except `malloc` & al so where do you get these untyped bytes from if you're writing your own `malloc` and not relying on them :D the effective type does not become permanently associated with the storage, you can always overwrite it by assignment!

Comment: *"If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value."*

Answer (score 1):

Consider an example (in c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct A {
    int x[10];
    int y[1];
};

int main()
{
  struct A *ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(struct A));
  ptr->x[10] = 4;
  printf("%i\n", ptr->x[10]);
  ptr = realloc(ptr, 80);  // realloc
  ptr->x[20] = 4;
  printf("%i\n", ptr->x[20]);
  free(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Now consider the following assembly code (relevant to the realloc function) (off course if you are interested):

```
  400604:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  400608:       be 50 00 00 00          mov    esi,0x50
  40060d:       48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
  400610:       e8 bb fe ff ff          call   4004d0 <realloc@plt>
  400615:       48 89 45 f8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
```

Now, in here, the pointer `ptr` is getting moved into the register `rax`, which eventually gets moved into the register `esi`. And the size of the pointer to be re-allocated into the register `rdi`. The line 4 is a call to the `realloc@GLIBC` function. Here pointer `ptr` must have been allocated previously by `malloc`, `calloc` (in this case) and `realloc` functions. In the last line, `rax` contains the pointer to the new memory region (returned by `realloc`) which is assigned to the pointer `ptr` (notice, rbp-0x8 is the location of the pointer on the stack).

**How is memory reallocated without knowing the length of the original memory?**

This `realloc` function in the standard library ([e.g. library code used](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc)) is defined as:

```
void * __libc_realloc (void *oldmem, size_t bytes)
```

Here, `*oldmem` is the pointer to the old memory, pointer `ptr` in our case. and `bytes` is the size to be allocated, `80` in our case. This function has a lot checks like, to check if the pointer is `null` if so, treat it as a simple `malloc` function, to check if the bytes are 0, if so treat it as a `free`, etc. We are interested in the following lines:

```
  /* chunk corresponding to oldmem */
  const mchunkptr oldp = mem2chunk (oldmem);
  /* its size */
  const INTERNAL_SIZE_T oldsize = chunksize (oldp);
```

It means that the all the information is being kept internally (in the malloc program headers, as pointed out previously by @SirDarius in the comments), i.e. every pointer and the size associated with it. If everything goes right, then it calls another function (in this case):

```
_int_realloc(mstate av, mchunkptr oldp, INTERNAL_SIZE_T oldsize,
             INTERNAL_SIZE_T nb)
```

This function allocates the actual size in the memory. and returns a new_pointer, which is eventually returned by `__libc_realloc` and we receive that in the register `rax`.

**How could I implement this function myself?**

If you are interested, you can look at the complete code [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#3136).